# Exposing what is *on-topic* to newcomers

Tags: discussion

When I go to the tour of a site (example: https://stackoverflow.com/tour), one of the first things I expect to see is: What topics are on-topic for this site.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But this is not so easy to find:

1. At the end of the tour I had to find: "Visit the help center" button
2. Then on this new page I had to find: "What topics can I ask about here?"

That is a long way just to know what type's of questions are on-topic here.

And if it's not on-topic... how do I find the site that is appropriate to my question?

(Hint: bottom of tour is [full list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#). But :-( no description what is on-topic for every site.)

Comment: Very near the beginning there is an "ask about" and "don't ask about" section which touches upon it. Not completely of course, but neither does the help center blurb you quoted. Push comes to shove you don't convey the knowledge of what question NOT to ask in a few generic bullets as each and every bullet is subject to opinion. Especially the "practical answerable problem that is unique to software development" bit I find gold, yeah that puts us all on the same page :)

Comment: *"Hint: bottom of tour is full list of sites. But :-( no description what is on-topic for every site."* - Of course! Why only go through steps 1 and 2 on one site when you can do it on every site

Comment: Well You do get a badge for every Tour You visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed But.. they're all the same!

Comment: @Gimby You're right. Didn't notice that. It looks like an example answer, not something I "have to read". Maybe just getting rid of that animation, would help make it more noticeable?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk  he he :) That goes to show how different people are, the animation is exactly what drew my eyes to it. You just can't win.

Comment: The question wizard should contain a part where they have to read the appropriate information about on topic, and perform a pop quiz to make sure they understand it. At the moment new contributes run a gauntlet of down-votes because a large majority of new contributor questions are just terrible, they have no idea, and don't even bother figuring it out. The current process is we are using our resources as contributors teaching them things which should have already been conveyed... It wastes everyone's time

Comment: @MichaelRandall True, a complete misunderstanding of what the site is about paired with being in a hurry to get help ASAP leads to many startup problems. I have full faith in the ability of the internet to produce a site with a list of all the questions and their expected answer within a week of release though.